# How can I get notified offchain when a transaction is included in a block that is validated?

Tags: cardano-node

I need to do an offchain action in an application when a transaction is included in a block that is validated.

Is there a way to register a listener for such a notification? Or is there another mechanism?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no listener for it. Pooling it in an interval is a common way to do that. The [Listening for ada payments using cardano-cli](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/listening-for-payments-cli/) page is worth referring to.

You can also watch the chain from [cardano-db-sync](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/) or from some Cardano API providers such as [Blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io).

If you use Blockfrost.io, you could use the [Websockets link for Blockfrost.io API](https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-websocket-link) to create a WebSocket subscription.

Comment: Did you find out a way to listen for transaction completion?